# chrome is not smooth when for animating a div's left property using jquery animate() method

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to create a simple image slider but I am having some trouble doing it
here is my code so far :

```
<div id="frame">
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="imageHolder">
      <img src="PNGs/Desert.jpg" alt="image" />
      <img src="PNGs/Lighthouse.jpg" alt="image" />
      <img src="PNGs/Penguins.jpg" alt="image" />
      <img src="PNGs/Hydrangeas.jpg" alt="image" />
      <img src="PNGs/Koala.jpg" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div id="counter"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="button1" style="z-index:100; position:absolute; right:-25px; top:175px; width:50px; height:35px; border-radius:200px; background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; vertical-align:central; padding-top:15px;">right</div>
  <div id="button2" style="z-index:100; position:absolute; left:-25px; top:175px; width:50px; height:35px; border-radius:200px; background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; vertical-align:central; padding-top:15px;">left</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#frame {
    margin:10px auto 0;
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px; 
}

#slider {
    position:relative; 
    width:1000px; 
    height:400px; 
    background-color:red; 
    overflow:hidden;
}

#imageHolder {
    width: 0;
    height:400px; 
    position:relative;
}

#imageHolder img {
    float:left; 
    width:1000px; 
    height:400px;
}

#counter {
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:100; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:10px; 
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function () {
            var count = $('#imageHolder img').length;
            var itemIndex = 1;
            function MoveSlider(container, count, isForwards) {
                var containerName = '#' + container.toString();
                if (isForwards) {
                    itemIndex++;
                    if (itemIndex < count + 1)
                        $(containerName).animate({ left: ((itemIndex - 1) * -100).toString() + "%" }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
                    else {
                        $(containerName).animate({ left: '0'}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
                        itemIndex = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    itemIndex--;
                    if (itemIndex > 0)
                        $(containerName).animate({ left: ((itemIndex - 1) * -100).toString() + "%" }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
                    else {
                        $(containerName).animate({ left: (-(count - 1) * 100).toString() + '%'}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
                        itemIndex = count;
                    }
                }
            }

            var counterHtml = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                counterHtml += "<div class=\"index\" style=\"text-align:center; vertical-align:central; color:white; display:inline-block; background-color:black;width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:200px;\">" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
            }
            $('#counter').html(counterHtml);
            $('#imageHolder').css('width', (count * 1000).toString() + 'px');

            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                MoveSlider('imageHolder', count, true);
            }, 5000);
            $('#frame').mouseover(function () {
                clearInterval(timer);
            });
            $('#frame').mouseleave(function () {
                timer = setInterval(function () {
                    MoveSlider('imageHolder', count, true);
                }, 5000);
            });
            $('.index').click(function () {
                itemIndex = $('.index').index(this) + 1;
                $('#imageHolder').animate({ left: ((itemIndex - 1) * -100).toString() + '%' }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
            });
            $('#button1').click(function () {
                MoveSlider('imageHolder', count, true);
            });
            $('#button2').click(function () {
                MoveSlider('imageHolder', count, false);
            });
        });
```

the animations run smoothly on firefox and IE10, but there is a significant lag for the first 2 or 3 images,and I have no idea what to do with it
Any suggestions about my problem?
(ps:any suggestion on my javascript code is also appreciated if you think I can make it better...)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try using css3 transitions for modern browser as they tend to be smoother, and then rely on the jquery animate as a fallback option

Comment: I had the exact same problem with css transitions.I used standard css3 transitions before I used the jquery.animate() method.but the lag i am talking about was still there!!!\

Comment: Could just be the size of your images then. Try reducing them and making them optimised for web, and then see if that helps. I noticed your div is 1000px wide, so if your images are too, and very high resolution, then this will put a strain on webkits resources

Comment: can you make a fiddle for us? I just tried with your code and it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/F7n9H/

Comment: Check out [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) for a better animation library ;)

Comment: I can not get my code to work in the fiddle and I have no idea why....,but it looks like the problem is with the images' sizes as @TimPalmer suggested